# How can I sort divs / posts with multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, function, html, hide

I want to make a tag system for my blog posts. If you click on the respective tag it should only show posts that contain this tag and hide the rest. So I tried to write an onClick-function but it failed. Why?

That's the HTML for the posts:

```
<div class="post lorem">
  <div class="postTitle">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="postInfo">Tags: <a onClick="sortPosts('lorem');">Lorem</a></div>
  <div class="postText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
</div>

<div class="post ipsum dolar">
  <div class="postTitle">
    <h1>Ipsum dolar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="postInfo">Tags: <a onClick="sortPosts('ipsum');">Ipsum</a> · <a onClick="sortPosts('dolar');">Dolar</a></div>
  <div class="postText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
</div>

<div class="post dolar">
  <div class="postTitle">
    <h1>Dolar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="postInfo">Tags: <a onClick="sortPosts('dolar');">Dolar</a></div>
  <div class="postText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.postInfo {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function sortPosts(tag) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('.post tag)')) {
    show();
  } else {
    hide();
  }
}
```

And all together in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrX7x/)…

Comment: With jQuery, this would be one line: `$('.post').hide().filter('.'+tag).show();`

Comment: @techfoobar Can't get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/LrX7x/2/ – it always hides everything…

Comment: You need to pass a valid value for the `tag` argument.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/LrX7x/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('.post ' + tag );
```

Now if there were any elements matched, you will iterate over them and set their style.display properties to none.

Note: This could be far easier with jQuery ;-) .

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I'm still stuck with the iteration part. I don't understand which elements have to match…

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` expects just class names. *Not selectors* like `.className`

Comment: @techfoobar  You mean like that: `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post' + tag );`?

Comment: @Retador - No more like: `document.getElementsByClassName('post ' + tag );` with a space between each class name.